# open camera using camera api in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to open camera in android without using intents. I want to setParameters of camera before opening the Camera. (e.g I want to set default orientation of camera view to "LandScape" before launching the camera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here. You can create your very own camera app using surface view http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html